# Снова не переведены модераторские действия

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора

[image: Question modal]

> Moderator actions

> Protect

> Add post notice

> Convert to wiki

> Lock

> Remove from hot network questions

> Show flag history

> Show review history

> Show timeline

[image: Bounty]

> Remove post notice

> Remove bounty

[image: Protect]

> This question is highly active and likely to receive spam activity or non-answers (e.g. "Me too!" "Thanks!"). Anonymous and low reputation users can’t answer protected questions.

[image: Add post notice]

> Citation Needed

[image: Объединение]

> Master question ID or URL

> Lookup

[image: Lock]

> Locking a post is a last resort that should only be used when other solutions aren't an option. A locked post cannot be deleted, edited, commented on or voted on, and if the locked post is a question, it can not be closed or reopened and no new answers can be added; existing unlocked answers on locked questions are not impacted by the lock except in the case of historical locks. See The Help Center for more details

> This post has been locked while disputes about its content are being resolved. You may discuss this on meta if you have concerns.

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. See the справка for guidance on writing a good question.

> This question’s answers are a collaborative effort. If you see something that can be improved, just edit the answer to improve it! No additional answers can be added here.

> How long should the lock last?

[image: Answer modal]

> Open chat room

> Purge all comments

> Show 8 deleted comments

[image: Answer with spam modal]

> Clear 1 rude or abusive/spam flags

Comment: И_так_сойдёт.jpg

Comment: Затрагивает очень небольшой круг лиц. Тем более, которые в состоянии самостоятельно исправить ситуацию к лучшему.

Comment: @Suvitruf, ещё 2 строки.

Comment: @Qwertiy вы, как модератор, можете сами эти строки добавлять и утверждать https://ru.traducir.win (:

Comment: Галочку поставьте (¬‿¬ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё приходится делать самому (￢_￢;)

Добавил переводы. После диплоя новой версии движка (вероятно, в понедельник) появятся.

**UPD:** по большей части всё выкатилось. Осталось пару строка. Пока не ясно, почему не перевелись. Подождём до следующего апдейта, если не появится, пойдём на MSE спрашивать. Вполне возможно, что опять не так константу подставили (¬‿¬ )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]